# Jupyter docker: Volume: Permission denied

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

### What docker image you are using?

jupyter/minimal-notebook

### What complete docker command do you run to launch the container (omitting sensitive values)?

```
# Creating a volume with docker create -- volume
docker volume create --name stagingarea
# Start a jupyter minimal notebook container and map the volume (stagingarea) to a container directory (/data/stagingarea)
docker run -d \
  -v stagingarea:/home/jovyan/stagingarea\
  -p 8888:8888 \
  jupyter/minimal-notebook
```

### What steps do you take once the container is running to reproduce the issue?

1. Visit http://localhost:8888 & Login with token
2. Go to /home/jovyan/stagingarea
3. Attempt to create a simple notebook, or text file (Greetings.txt) in the volume

### What do you expect to happen?

- I want to: Create a simple text file and save it in the volume
- In order to: share this text file with other containers

### What actually happens?

- I have this error message: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1175888/12765291/4ce76dfe-c9fe-11e5-86e0-b952c8a65777.png
- Similar to this issue: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/114

### Why I want to do that

- I want to create a staging area so a python program  in jupyter can download data from one source, write it to a docker volume, and another service (like postgres,..) can read data from that volume and ingest it.

### What I tried:

#### Connecting as root

- It works when I run the jupyter docker image. as root -e GRANT_SUDO=yes \

```
# Creating a volume with docker create -- volume
docker volume create --name stagingarea
# Start a jupyter minimal notebook container and map the volume (stagingarea) to a container directory (/data/stagingarea)
docker run -d \
  -v stagingarea:/home/jovyan/stagingarea\
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -e JUPYTER_TOKEN=letmein \
  -e GRANT_SUDO=yes \
  --user root \
  jupyter/minimal-notebook
```

#### Using a bind mount

```
docker run -d \
  -v -v /Users/paulogier/87-docker_parent/usingjupyterwithdocker/Step7_Volumes/stagingarea:/home/jovyan/stagingarea )
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -e JUPYTER_TOKEN=letmein \
  jupyter/minimal-notebook
```

Comment: Closed through https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1187

Answer (score 5):

Closed through: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1187
It requires to run the container with --user root, same as solution I proposed.